# How to fetch data from custom table in Corda

Tags: kotlin, corda

We are trying to fetch data from the our custom tables using the vault query with state as query criteria. But we get a state with a model class which contains the old values and not the new ones from the database. Can someone point out to an example of fetching the data from a custom table and mapping it to the model class in corda.

Comment: Do you have your own schema implemented?

Comment: yes..its mapped in the state class..

Comment: Can you paste your code, please? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Mapping from the schema to state's properties can be provided in the state class by overriding the method *generateMappedObject* from the QueryableState class. Make sure your state implements *QueryableState* class.

```
@Override public PersistentState generateMappedObject(MappedSchema schema) {
        if (schema instanceof IOUSchemaV1) {
            return new IOUSchemaV1.PersistentIOU(
                    this.lender.getName().toString(),
                    this.borrower.getName().toString(),
                    this.value,
                    this.linearId.getId());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised schema $schema");
        }
    }
```

You can then query the database using vault query like

```
QueryCriteria queryCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria().withStatus(Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED);

List<StateAndRef<IOUState>> iouStates = getServiceHub().getVaultService()
                .queryBy(IOUState, queryCriteria).getStates();
```